# Does System.Threading.Timer consume a thread while waiting?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I start a System.Threading.Timer, does it consume a ThreadPool thread while waiting (bad), or only when the timer is executing the TimerCallback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only when the callback is being executed. Note that if the duration of the callback is longer than the timer interval multiple thread pool threads will end up executing the callback concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  And no.  It depends on your .NET framework version.  Traditionally no, it consumed an entire thread.  Started by the CLR to handle *all* active timers.

Not so on more recent versions, like my 4.5.1 running on Windows 8.1.  It has switched to using [CreateTimerQueueTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get that job done.  That's pooled by the operating system.

Get insight by enabling unmanaged debugging and setting a breakpoint on the timer's callback.  Look at the call stack.

Comment: So in early versions, the single "management" thread is a ThreadPool thread, while in current versions it is pooled outside of the thread pool.  I'm more concerned about what happens if you have several hundred timers running.

Comment: No, it was a real thread.  And no, there's no need to worry about hundreds of timers.  The scheme is simple, only one thread is every needed to handle any number of timers.  Thousands are fine. All it has to do is wait for the *first* timer that's due to expire.  Once it ticks, or another timer is added or changed, all that's needed is to find the next one that's due.  Easy peasy.